# Sphinxsearch - how do I find items with the most similar tags?

Tags: mysql, sphinx, sphinxql

I have a `posts` index with MVA `tag`, config similar to the following:

```
source posts {
    sql_query       = SELECT id, title, text FROM posts;
    sql_attr_multi  = uint tag from query; SELECT postid, tagid FROM tagstoposts
}
```

Now for a given post I want to find all the other posts that have the closest tags, e.g.

- Post 1: cats, cute, funny
- Post 2: cats, cute, serious
- Post 3: dogs, cute
- Post 4: ISIS

Here for the post 1 I'd like to find post 2 (since it has 2 matching tags), then post 3 (1 matching tag). How do I do this using SphinxQL?

I've managed to get what I want using the following query:

`select id, in(tag,55)+in(tag,1321) AS shitfix from posts where match('') and tag in (55,1321) ORDER BY shitfix DESC;`

But it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: Well you dont need the empty match, so `... where tag in ...` would be fine. But otherwise that seems fine. There isnt a variation of IN() that tells you how *many* are matched.